# Jquery UI Tabs and spring mvc

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jquery-ui-tabs

I do not really now much about javascript but found on the web the jquery ui tabs and wanted to give it a try.

They work out of the box however when I have within one tab a form that send information to the back end. The response (sent back from an spring mvc controller) is unable to come back to the same location. As a result is gone to a page without tabs or it position it self at the end of the tab content.

is there somethin I need to do?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            }
        }

    });
});
<ul>
     <li><a href="/home/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/"><span>Admin</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="/support/"><span>Support</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using ajax to send the form in the tab? If you don't use ajax and you just send the form it's normal that the browser puts the returned page substituting the current one. You need ajax to place updated content in the current tab.

You have to send the form in this way (for example with jquery, I haven't tested it, sorry if there is any misspelling):

```
<form id="my_form">
     ....
</form>

<div id="response_container">
    here I want to see the response
</div>
```

and the javascript to send and receive the response:

```
//catch the submit event in the form
$("#my_form").submit(function(){
   //when the form is going to be submitted it is sent as an ajax request
   //so the answer can be placed in the current page
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: $("#my_form").attr('action'),
       data: $("#my_form").serializeArray(),
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(msg){
            //place the returned html response whenever you want
            $("#response_container").html(msg);
        }
   });

   //return false to avoid the default submit() behaiour can take place
   return false;
});
```

Comment: @tsunade21 in the same page where the form is (it's javascript it must be executed when the browser can read the form). The important thing is that you understand what it does. It catches the event "the form is going to be sent" and intead of sending it it sends the form as an ajax request. As it iss sent with ajax you can place the response wherever you want.

Comment: @Javi: where do I declare msg?

Comment: @tsunade21 you don't have to declare message. msg is the variable returned by ajax which contains the response from the ajax request. More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Javi: I am using Spring 3 mvc on the backend, do I need to return anything special to the front end?

Comment: @tsunade21 you just have to return the content of the tab. It is usually placed in a JSP. Inside the JSP you don't have to have html head and body tags because they are in the current page and you just want to insert some code inside a div (or wherever you want to place it) of the tag. So you have to use the Spring Controller method in the same way as when you show a page, but retrning only the fragment you need to update.